# In "eshoponcontainers", most of the dockerfiles have copy(all csproj) and restore, does it not make overhaed on container?

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I can see comment in each dockfile

> ## Keep the project list and command dotnet restore identical in all Dockfiles to maximize image cache utilization

But I have confusion with,

1. it would build the fast(due to caching) but does it not take extra space in
   container FS.
2. And in future if I add new project in solution should I make to
   change every dockerfile.

Here https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Basket/Basket.API/Dockerfile basket-api docfile have copy command on projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for doing this is to take advantage of Docker's layer caching. Yes, there is maintenance overhead to ensure that the list here reflects the actual set of project files that are defined in the repo.

The caching optimization comes into play for iterative development scenarios (inner loop). In those scenarios, you're typically making changes to source code files, not the project files. If you haven't changed any project files since you last built the Dockerfile, you get to take advantage of Docker's layer caching and skip the restoration of NuGet packages for those projects, which can be quite time consuming.

Yes, there is a small amount of extra space being included in the container image because the project files end up getting copied twice which results in duplicate data amongst the two layers. But that's fairly small because project files aren't that big.

There are always tradeoffs. In this case, the desire is to have a fast inner loop build time at the expense of maintenance and a small amount of extra space in the container image.